# Presenting text with horizontal and vertical scrollbars?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3, I would like to present two json blobs side by side. I would like to use horizontal or vertical scrollbars to keep the json readable (as opposed to breaking the lines).

Hopefully, it would look something like this:

[image]

Instead, it looks like this:

[image]

using this code:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #ddd">
                    [
                    {
                    "_id": "5d2f47bc79a22d920c706366",
                    "index": 0,
                    "guid": "cd32479c-ebdd-4de5-ab46-eeb5bbdcda39",
                    "isActive": false,
                    "balance": "$3,303.69",
                    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
                    "age": 21,
                    "eyeColor": "brown",
                    "name": "Montgomery Freeman",
                    "gender": "male",
                    "company": "EVENTIX",
                    "email": "montgomeryfreeman@eventix.com",
                    "phone": "+1 (891) 433-2525",
                    "address": "757 Beard Street, Roulette, West Virginia, 7144",
                    "about": "Qui reprehenderit aliquip est anim Lorem elit fugiat. Et quis esse enim consectetur laboris laboris commodo Lorem exercitation ad sunt. Officia nulla commodo amet occaecat fugiat officia dolor mollit. Velit ut reprehenderit cillum duis tempor dolore elit duis tempor aute Lorem ea excepteur. Velit id id elit occaecat minim eiusmod qui ipsum nisi. Dolor pariatur anim ipsum culpa. Dolor nulla eiusmod ut sit voluptate excepteur nisi culpa proident aliquip esse.\r\n",
                    "registered": "2015-12-21T07:31:05 +05:00",
                    "latitude": 43.355285,
                    "longitude": 61.420368,
                    "tags": [
                    "ut",
                    "consequat",
                    "nisi",
                    "qui",
                    "et",
                    "exercitation",
                    "quis"
                    ],
                    "friends": [
                    {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Crystal Mcdowell"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Grace Gilbert"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Stevens Frost"
                    }
                    ],
                    "greeting": "Hello, Montgomery Freeman! You have 9 unread messages.",
                    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
                    }
                    ]
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: #ddd">
                    [
                    {
                    "_id": "5d2f47bc79a22d920c706366",
                    "index": 0,
                    "guid": "cd32479c-ebdd-4de5-ab46-eeb5bbdcda39",
                    "isActive": false,
                    "balance": "$3,303.69",
                    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
                    "age": 21,
                    "eyeColor": "brown",
                    "name": "Montgomery Freeman",
                    "gender": "male",
                    "company": "EVENTIX",
                    "email": "montgomeryfreeman@eventix.com",
                    "phone": "+1 (891) 433-2525",
                    "address": "757 Beard Street, Roulette, West Virginia, 7144",
                    "about": "Qui reprehenderit aliquip est anim Lorem elit fugiat. Et quis esse enim consectetur laboris laboris commodo Lorem exercitation ad sunt. Officia nulla commodo amet occaecat fugiat officia dolor mollit. Velit ut reprehenderit cillum duis tempor dolore elit duis tempor aute Lorem ea excepteur. Velit id id elit occaecat minim eiusmod qui ipsum nisi. Dolor pariatur anim ipsum culpa. Dolor nulla eiusmod ut sit voluptate excepteur nisi culpa proident aliquip esse.\r\n",
                    "registered": "2015-12-21T07:31:05 +05:00",
                    "latitude": 43.355285,
                    "longitude": 61.420368,
                    "tags": [
                    "ut",
                    "consequat",
                    "nisi",
                    "qui",
                    "et",
                    "exercitation",
                    "quis"
                    ],
                    "friends": [
                    {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Crystal Mcdowell"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Grace Gilbert"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Stevens Frost"
                    }
                    ],
                    "greeting": "Hello, Montgomery Freeman! You have 9 unread messages.",
                    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
                    }
                    ]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd rather not use `pre` elements (which often change font and other things), just set the wrap and overflow properties as needed:

```
.inner { /* a wrapper for your text */
    white-space: pre;
}
.outer { /* maybe on your column element */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 1):

`<pre>` tag can help you in this case.

JS Code:
`document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);`

HTML Code:
`<pre id="json"></pre>`

Enable Scrolling for 
`<div style="overflow:auto;"><pre id="json"></pre></div>`